# How can I zomm 2x or zomm 3x when CameraX library in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-camera2

I use  CameraX library in my project, the *view_finder* control displays the picture of a mobile phone camera.

I hope to zoom the picture 2x or 3x, I think the *Code A* can do it.

I wonder if the algorithm of *Code A* is correct. Is there a simple algorithm to zoom 4x ,5x, ...10x ?

BTW,  `preview = AutoFitPreviewBuilder.build(viewFinderConfig, viewFinder)` , you can see a [simple code](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/blob/master/CameraXBasic/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/cameraxbasic/utils/AutoFitPreviewBuilder.kt).

**Code A**

```
fun zoom2(){
    val left1=viewFinder.width/3
    val right1=viewFinder.width/3*2
    val top1=viewFinder.height/3
    val bottom1=viewFinder.height/3*2

    val my = Rect(left1, top1, right1, bottom1)
    preview?.zoom(my)
}

fun zoom3(){
    val left2=viewFinder.width/6*2.5
    val right2=viewFinder.width/6*3.5
    val top2=viewFinder.height/6*2.5
    val bottom2=viewFinder.height/6*3.5

    val my = Rect(left2.toInt(), top2.toInt(), right2.toInt(), bottom2.toInt())
    preview?.zoom(my) 
}
```

**Layout**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/camera_container"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextureView
        android:id="@+id/view_finder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```